# Make unittests fail on logger.warning calls

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'd like my Python `unittest` tests to fail if I see any warnings written to the logger.  How do I capture logger messages and fail the test on them?

Answer (score 1):

`unittest` has [`assertLogs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLogs) context manager for capturing log records (added since Python 3.4, for older versions use [`unittest2`](https://pypi.org/project/unittest2/) backport lib). Usage example:

`spam.py` (code to be tested)

```
import logging
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(logging.NullHandler())


def eggs():
    logging.warning('hello world')
```

Test:

```
import unittest
import spam

class SpamTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_eggs(self):
        with self.assertLogs() as ctx:
            spam.eggs()
        # we expect one record to be captured
        self.assertEqual(len(ctx.records), 1)
        record = ctx.records[0]
        # we expect the captured record to have the message 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(record.message, 'hello world')
```

If you want to fail the test on any records with warning level, you can e.g. check against the captured records, filtered by level:

```
self.assertFalse([r for r in ctx.records if r.levelno == logging.WARNING])
```

Comment: I had made a change that introduced warnings to several of 100's of tests in multiple directories. Rather than run all the tests, I was hoping to stop testing immediately so I could fix the warning.

Comment: This isn't clear from your question. So instead of writing new tests, you want to fail existing tests that encounter any warning logged?

Answer (score 1):

When nothing is logged, `self.assertLogs()` contextManager emits an `AssertionError: no logs of level WARNING or higher triggered on root`.

We want exactly the opposite.

Here is the snippet I wrote to avoid that:

```py
import logging
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def assertNoLog(self, level='WARNING'):
    with self.assertLogs(level=level) as cm:
        yield
        logging.error("gotcha ! with 1 log, you cannot fail before I check ;p")
    if cm.output[:-1]:  # let's remove this last log
        for r in cm.records[:-1]:
            print(r)  # print full failing logs for debug
        raise AssertionError("Log with level >= {level} received".format(level=level),
                             cm.output[:-1])
```

and in the unit tests:

```py
def test_my_program(self):
    with assert_no_log(self):
        logging.warning('Oh no! an Unexpected warning! This should fail tests!')
```

which returns:

```
AssertionError: ('Log with level >= WARNING received', 
    ['WARNING:my.module:Oh no! an Unexpected warning! This should fail tests!'])
```

Answer (score 0):

For a true unittest you will actually want to mock the call to the logger.warning using patch. You can then use that mock to assert if the function was called, called with certain parameters, or not even called at all using the patch with the methods: assert_called_once(), assert_called_once_with() and assert_not_called(). [Patching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) is great!

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from logging import warning


def simple_function(value):

    if value == 5:
        pass
    else:
        warning(msg='msg')


class TestSimpleFunction(TestCase):

    @patch('test_stack_overflow.warning')
    def test_simple_function_wrong_value(self, log_warning_call):
        simple_function('5')
        log_warning_call.assert_called_once()
        log_warning_call.assert_called_once_with(msg='msg')

    @patch('test_stack_overflow.warning')
    def test_simple_function_right_value(self, log_warning_call):
        simple_function(5)
        log_warning_call.assert_not_called()
```